# WPF and user interface freeze

Tags: wpf, user-interface, mvvm, task, freeze

In my main window, I have

- a navigation treeview on the left
- a content presenter on the right
- some kind of please wait panel (with width and height approximately 50) which displays a loading gif; this panel's visibility is binded to my main window's viewmodel bool property IsBusy.

The idea is showing this panel when the content presenter is initialized.

---

Selecting an item in the treeview:

1. sets the bool property IsBusy to true (thus the wait panel with the
   loading gif shows)
2. sets the content presenter

To initialize this content, I use a task in my main window viewmodel so that the UI remains responsive. Within this task, when I need to update the UI, I use Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke to manipulate my UI thread. This way, my loading gif plays smoothly when the task is processed in another thread.

---

Now, let's say I have a datagrid with twenty columns in my content presenter which is binded to an ObservableCollection in my main viewmodel. In my task, if I add 1000 items to this collection, when the UI updates to display the content, it becomes unresponsive for a few tenths of a second and my gif stop; basically the UI freezes.

How could I ensure that the wait panel always remains responsive and the gif keeps playing smoothly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, all I had to do was create the content presenter's content in another thread then assign the result to my content presenter after everything is done (in the bgw RunWorkCompleted for instance).